# Failed to get credentials when calling Ansible using Local PowerShell

Tags: powershell, ansible, azure-automation, azure-authentication

I have an Ansible code on an Ubuntu Virtual Machine in Azure VM. when I am connected to my VM using SSH directly with softwares like [Bitwise](https://www.bitvise.com/ssh-client-download), there is no problem in the code and I can run it without any error. but I need to Run my Ansible code using my local system PowerShell. When I am calling Ansiable command using my PowerShell, I will get bellow error:

#### PowerShell Command:

```
PS C:\Users\Reza> New-SSHSession -ComputerName "13.**.**.***" -Credential ubuntu -KeyFile "C:\Users\Reza\Desktop\ndbench\Azure\Automation\01_get_metrics\ssh\myPrivateKey_rsa"
PS C:\Users\Reza> (Invoke-SSHCommand -Index 0 -Command "sudo pwsh /root/test.ps1").Output
```

#### Output:

```
SessionId  Host                                                                      Connected                                                          
---------  ----                                                                      ---------                                                          
    0      13.**.**.***                                                                 True
PLAY [Create Azure VM] *********************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Create VM] ***************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to get credentials. Either pass as parameters, set environment variables, define a profi
le in ~/.azure/credentials, or install Azure CLI and log in (`az login`)."}
    to retry, use: --limit @/home/ubuntu/azure_create_vm.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Can you please guide me why I am getting this error and how I can solve it?

P.S. 1: I have tried Putty and the error was same. seems if I call my Ansible from another device remotely (using SSH), I will get same error.
P.S. 2: I have tried to login from local machine using `az login` in PowerShell and Putty and there wasn't any change in the error.

Comment: I recommend you to read how using [Azure Credentials ](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/scenario_guides/guide_azure.html)under Ansibble documentation. You have the option to use a credentials file and environment variables.

Comment: @imjoseangel thanks for it, but the link is not working

Comment: [Providing Credentials to Azure Modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/scenario_guides/guide_azure.html#providing-credentials-to-azure-modules)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about that. Bad copy/paste.

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/scenario_guides/guide_azure.html